# Flask_PyMongo: TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, flask, pymongo

This simple piece of code reduced from a much larger piece generates an error on the pymongo 'find' call:

```
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from os import environ

CLIENT_PATH = "/api/v1.0"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = environ.get('MONGODB_URI', "mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route(CLIENT_PATH, methods=['GET'])
def getClients():
        data = []
        cursor = mongo.db.client.find({}, {"_id": 0})
        for item in cursor:
            client_detail = {}
            client_detail['url'] = CLIENT_PATH + "/" + str(item.get('id'))
            client_detail['clientTitle'] = str(item.get('firstName')) + " " + str(item.get("familyName"))
            data.append(client_detail)
        return jsonify({"status": "success", "payload": data})

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

and if i run this with python 2.7 and make a call from the browser on 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0' I get the following error message:

```
      File "/Users/markschulz/Projects/client/flask-client/app.py", line 16, in getClients
    cursor = mongo.db.client.find({}, {"_id": 0})
  File "/Users/markschulz/Projects/client/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1116, in __call__
    self.__name, self.__client.__class__.__name__))
  TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'find' method on a 'MongoClient' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Software versions in use are: pymongo==3.4.0 Flask==0.12 Flask-PyMongo==0.4.1

What goes here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```
mongo.db.collection.find({}, {"_id": 0})
```

Where "db" is the name of your database and "collection" is the name of your collection.